# Can't access Kubernetes dashboard after reinstall it from Rancher server

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, rancher

The first time install Kubernetes environment from Rancher server was successful.

Removed it and installed it again, all the stack went green, but when access Kubernetes dashboard, there just a blank page.

Check dashboard's container log:

```
$ docker ps -a | grep dash
0b8129ff9809        gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64    "/dashboard --inse..."   36 seconds ago       Exited (1) 30 seconds ago                         k8s_kubernetes-dashboard_kubernetes-dashboard-5ffb9c9bb7-v5mhw_kube-system_2fe1595e-d35b-11e7-bf25-0264f6c60326_4
ab246945e1c6        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0               "/pause"                 2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                                      k8s_POD_kubernetes-dashboard-5ffb9c9bb7-v5mhw_kube-system_2fe1595e-d35b-11e7-bf25-0264f6c60326_0

$ docker logs 0b81
2017/11/27 10:16:16 Starting overwatch
2017/11/27 10:16:16 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2017/11/27 10:16:16 Using service account token for csrf signing
2017/11/27 10:16:16 No request provided. Skipping authorization
2017/11/27 10:16:21 Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service accounts configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a server that does not exist. Reason: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
Refer to the troubleshooting guide for more information: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.md
```

What will be the problem?

[image]

---

## Addition

### OS

```
CentOS 7
```

### Rancher

```
v1.6.11
```

### Docker

```
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:41:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:49 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the message you received:

> 2017/11/27 10:16:21 Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes
>   apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured
>   (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service accounts
>   configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a server that
>   does not exist. **Reason: the server has asked for the client to
>   provide credentials** Refer to the troubleshooting guide for more
>   information:
>   https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.md

The server requires credentials, read the troubleshooting guide to find out how to correct it.

Comment: But the first time I installed Kubernetes, it's successful. I don't know how to do with the notice. And, the troubleshooting page on github now can't been visited.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade docker version, your version is not supported by Rancher.
Read more at [this link.](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/hosts/#supported-docker-versions)

Comment: The reason was `etcd` volume didn't removed from k8s clusters.